# nth-child(2n) doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, frontend

What's wrong with this code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div id="entry1">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry2">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry3">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry4">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry5">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry6">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.post {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #222;
}

.post:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**FIDDLE → https://jsfiddle.net/twvxzhwm/**

Why doesn't `nth-child(2n)` work?

What should I do to repair that?

P.S: I cant change #entry$ → it's from CMS.
I can use only CSS or JS.

Comment: `div:nth-child(2n) > .post`

Comment: its not working because `.post ` is always the `first-child` inside div `id="entry#"`.

Comment: @gcampbell, it's good idea, thx ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nthchild is a very specific css rule, and can be used in many ways.

For example:

My HTML:

```
<ul class='item-container my-class'>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    </ul>
```

Selecting the first 5 elements:

```
.my-class > * :nth-child(-n+5) {
    display: block;
}
```

Selecting the fifth element:

```
.my-class > * :nth-child(5) {
    display: block;
}
```

For more information on the nth-child selector see: http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 1):

It's because they're not direct siblings, you had the right idea though, this is one way you can solve it.

```css
.post {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #222;
}
.clearfix div:nth-child(2n) > .post {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div id="entry1">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry2">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry3">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry4">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry5">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="entry6">
    <div class="post"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice I'm selecting `.clearfix div:nth-child(2n)` which means within .clearfix select every second div.

Then I'm saying `> .post` meaning to the selections children with the class post add the following the styles, background-color in this instance.

I hope that's clear.